# names for $f^{-1}(0)$

Tags: big-list

What are commonly-used names for $f^{-1}(0)$, where $f: X \to Y$ for $Y$ some algebraic structure with $0$?

I am particularly thinking of the case where $Y = \mathbb{R}$, where I was expecting that anti-support would be common (surprisingly it doesn't seem to be used at all), but for completeness I figured I should include other algebraic structures.

By commonly-used, it is sufficient that it be in some textbook used at an accredited university or college by someone other than the author themselves. Please list a source if it's not an exceedingly common term (maybe even if it is), and also the field(s) it is used in.

Comment: Kernel; $\operatorname{ker} f=\{x\in X : f(x)=0\}$

Comment: I've seen [zero set of $f$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeroSet.html) being used.

Comment: More generally, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(mathematics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the most common term for $f^{-1}(0)$ is the kernel of $f$, which is used almost universally in modern algebra, and can be found in any introductory text on the subject (e.g. I.N. Herstein's "Topics in Algebra").

In linear algebra, the most common term is "null space" to describe the kernel of a matrix. This is also relatively universal, for instance see Strang's "Introduction to Linear Algebra". As far as I know, it is not used outside of linear algebra, however.

A somewhat less common term is "zero fiber". The term "fiber of $y$ under $f$" is a common term for $f^{-1}(y)$ in naive set theory and analysis (in my impression), but zero fiber as its own term only seems to come up occasionally, as in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.07306).

Last, "zero set" seems to be a relatively common term, especially in analysis and topology. According to [planetmath](https://planetmath.org/zerosetofatopologicalspace), this appears to be related to the term "level set", which is common in analysis and topology.

Comment: Level set is an absurdly common phrase in maths. I see it used constantly in differential topology (clear example being Morse Theory). In such a context one usually thinks of the preimage of $0$ as being a (potentially singular) submanifold, being nonsingular iff $0$ is a regular value. As an aside, another term I commonly hear used is "vanishing set".

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen good to know. I changed it to "common in analysis and topology", which I think adequately describes where it is usually found.